# Send SOAP Request with Django

Tags: django, soap, pysimplesoap

First time using SOAP and wondering how can I make a simple SOAP request using django? I haven't yet tried setting up pysimplesoap, I first just want to make a connection to the webservice.

I have a string of the XML header and body

```
xml_header = ""
xml_body = ""
```

How can I send this request and wait for a response?

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.4 for SUDS is not an option

Comment: Ended up using SUDS jurko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the Suds library in your view: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/

Documentation: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Hi @Brandon, I am using suds for requesting async SOAP api it is working fine but not getting any response from it. hr is my Q.:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227719/asynchronous-soap-api-call-using-python please help in that, Thanks you

Comment: Opening the links gives out this message - "fedorahosted.org was retired on March 1st, 2017".

Answer (score 5):

Another library worth checking out is Zeep.

Some of the more complex SOAP transactions are virtually impossible with SUDS, but are simple within ZEEP.

http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/